# How can I troubleshoot "No valid ports are available." in VSCode using Docker/Postgres on specific workspace/project?

Tags: postgresql, docker, visual-studio-code

I frequently run docker on projects in VSCode using the Docker extension. For some reason, on one particular project, when I run my docker-compose file, all containers start correctly. However when I try to view the application (`mos_rms_app_prod` in my case) in my browser, I receive a VS Code error stating "No valid ports are available."

[image]

There was a similar case recorded on [GitHub Issues for vscode-docker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2897) but the issue was closed as it was unreproducible, so it clearly is something within my workspace.

Any ideas where I could go to debug? Possibly something related to Postgres?

My docker compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  # database
  loadbalancer:
    build: deploy/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./run/static/:/var/www/mos_rms_app_prod/static
    networks:
      - mos-web-nw

  db:
    image: postgres:13.0
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432
    # persistent db
    volumes:
      - prod-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - mos-db-nw

  # db GUI
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - mos-db-nw

#   web application
  web:
    build: .
    image:  mos_rms_app_prod:v0.1.0
    volumes:
      - .:/mos-rms
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mos-db-nw
      - mos-web-nw
networks:
  mos-db-nw:
    driver: bridge
  mos-web-nw:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  prod-db-data:
```